# Detect if Modifier Key is Pressed in KeyRoutedEventArgs Event

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

I have the following code:

```
public void tbSpeed_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !((e.Key >= 48 && e.Key <= 57) || (e.Key >= 96 && e.Key <= 105) || (e.Key == 109) || (e.Key == 189));
}
```

Is there any way to detect if any modifier key like shift is being pressed ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.getkeystate). e.g.

```
var state = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift);
return (state & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;
```

**Note**: For Alt, you would use VirtualKey.Menu.

Answer (score 7):

For Win10 UWP I noticed that the CTRL and SHIFT keys were set at Locked state.  So I did the following:

```
var shiftState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift);
var ctrlState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);

var isShiftDown = shiftState != CoreVirtualKeyStates.None;
var isCtrlDown = ctrlState != CoreVirtualKeyStates.None;
```

Comment: It is actually even better to use the `HasFlag` method - `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift).HasFlag( CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down )` - because this way you avoid the situation where the key is only locked but not actually pressed.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for WinUI 3-specific approach (`CoreWindow` is not available there), use the `InputKeyboardSource.GetKeyStateForCurrentThread` method:

```cs
var state = InputKeyboardSource.GetKeyStateForCurrentThread(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Shift);
var isShiftPressed = state.HasFlag(Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
CoreVirtualKeyStates controlKeyState = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
var  ctrl = (controlKeyState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;

CoreVirtualKeyStates shiftKeyState = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift);
var shift = (shiftKeyState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;
```

Answer (score -1):

`Bitwise AND` the `Modifiers` property of Keyboard with `Shift` Key -

```
bool isShiftKeyPressed = (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift)
                         == ModifierKeys.Shift;
```

Try this too-

```
bool isShiftKeyPressed = (ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift;
```

OR

```
Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift
```

Comment: I hate comments that are so vague as to be misleading. What @Elmo should have said is, that code is perfectly fine and dandy, except the `Keyboard` class is not available under UWP.