# SHIFT + Scroll to Scroll Horizontally in ScrollViewer UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, event-handling, scrollviewer

I would like to enable holding down SHIFT on the keyboard while scrolling to scroll a `ScrollViewer` horizontally.

I learned from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/handle-pointer-input) that the `PointerWheelChanged` event is the one I am looking for. Handling that, however, doesn't work because the `ScrollViewer` handles it internally, so my handler is never called. To get around that, I used the `AddHandler` method, as described in the ["Routed Events Overview"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview) article.

This works... but appears to be running my code AFTER the `ScrollViewer`runs its internal code. The result of this is that the `ScrollViewer` content pans vertically, then horizontally. They appear to happen in that order, and setting `e.Handled = true` doesnt stop it.

Is there a way to "intercept" the scroll, so I can handle it with my own logic, thus allowing the `ScrollViewer` to pan horizontally if SHIFT is pressed? I recently asked a similar question (involving intercepting input to a control so I could handle it with my own logic) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730458/use-shift-enter-for-multiline-textbox-in-uwp), where the answer involved handling a different event, where that event took place prior to control running its own logic. I do not see a similar "pre stuff happening" event for the pointer scroll.

The code I have follows. Note that the `ScrollViewer` can scroll BOTH horizontally and vertically, as well as zoom:

```
<!-- Contained in Grid in a UserControl, if that's relevant -->
<ScrollViewer Name="MyCanvasScrollViewer"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ZoomMode="Enabled"
              ZoomSnapPointsType="Optional"
              PointerWheelChanged="MyCanvasScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged">
    <!-- Content to pan -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code-behind:

```
// Constructor for the user contol.
public MyControl()
{
    // Add the scroll wheel event handler and force it to run.
    this.MyCanvasScrollViewer.AddHandler(ScrollViewer.PointerWheelChangedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(this.MyCanvasScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged), true);

    // Other un-related stuff omitted here...
}

// Event handler for the Pointer Wheel Changed event.
private void MyCanvasScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // If SHIFT is pressed...
    var keyState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift);
    if ((keyState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
    {
        // Get the amount to scroll.
        PointerPoint pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.WallCanvasScrollViewer);
        double scrollWheelDelta = pointer.Properties.MouseWheelDelta;

        // Change the view in the scroll viewer.
        this.MyCanvasScrollViewer.ChangeView(scrollWheelDelta, null, null, true);

        // Mark event as handled.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply disable `VerticalScrollMode` in `shift` **keydown** and enable it on **keyup**. No need for `pointerwheelchanged` itself. It works perfectly fine.

Xaml

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" x:Name="MyScrollViewer"  HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
   <Image Height="600" Width="500" Source="/Assets/1.jpg"></Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

//C# code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += MainPage_KeyDown;
        CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyUp += MainPage_KeyUp; ;
    }

    private void MainPage_KeyUp(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Shift)
        {                
            MyScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled = true;
            MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
        }
    }

    private void MainPage_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Shift)
        {
            MyScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled = false;
            MyScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That seems to mostly work. I have content in the `ScrollViewer` that is much lager in both the X and Y. While holding SHIFT does allow horizontal scrolling, the `ScrollViewer` first jumps to a specific vertical scroll value before scrolling horizontally... regardless of what my vertical value is when I start the horizontal scrolling. Thoughts?

Comment: Further inspection suggests that its jumping such that the content is centered vertically in the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Setting MyScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled = false; in key down and enabling it. Make the jump to stop. I have edited my answer

Comment: Setting `IsScrollInertiaEnabled = false` does indeed solve the vertical snapping, but of course then the nice fluid flow we are all used to goes away. Not the end of the world, but I wonder if there's a way to have the best of both worlds