# How to detect Control + not VirtualKey keyboard combinations?

Tags: c#, uwp, keyboard-shortcuts, keyevent

I'm setting a global keyboard shortcuts working on single pages, like `Ctrl + someKey` to do something, `Ctrl + Alt + otherKey` to activate some other things and so on. I have more or less working code for `Ctrl + VirtualKey` (Letters, numbers, ...) but I need also some keys that are not in the `VirtualKey` like, dot, comma, plus, minus, ...

These are the events registered:

```
public Planner()
{
        this.InitializeComponent();

        CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
        CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().CharacterReceived += Planner_CharacterReceived;
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
}
```

I use `KeyDown` for `Ctrl + K`, `Ctrl + Shift + A` like shortcuts.

`CharacterReceived` to capture comma, dot, plus, minus like characters, but they don't work with Ctrl and Alt.

Last, `Dispatcher_AcceleratorKey` to check if Alt key is pressed.

Comment: These keys were intentionally omitted from the VirtualKey enum.  They are the OEM keys, keyboard manufacturers can put them anywhere they like.  Or omit them completely.  It is not uncommon that a user somewhere in the world has to hit a special key first to get the character.  Which made them poor choices for shortcut keys in a framework that targets the entire world.  You can still use CharacterReceived, you [need this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13010409/17034).

Comment: As I pointed above, I'm using CharacterReceived to capture comma, dot, plus, minus keys, but in combination with Ctrl or Alt, they don't trigger the event. It's like any special key (Ctrl, Alt or shift) blocks the trigger from happening.

Maybe it's because the character result it's not a CharaterReceived.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, UWP does not support register global hot key, but you could response windows shortcut in app internal like the following.

First, register for accelerator key events used for button hotkeys.

```
public MainPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  // Register for accelerator key events used for button hotkeys
  Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated;
}
```

Detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>.

```
private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.EventType.ToString().Contains("Down"))
    {
        var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
        if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
        {
            switch (args.VirtualKey)
            {
                case VirtualKey.V:
                    ViewOrders_Tapped(this, null);
                    break;
                case VirtualKey.N:
                    NewOrder_Tapped(this, null);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For three key such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

```
private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.EventType.ToString().Contains("Down"))
    {
        var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
        var shift = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift);
        if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) && shift.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
        {
            switch (args.VirtualKey)
            {
                case VirtualKey.V:

                    break;
                case VirtualKey.N:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I got so far. I'm currently using these 3 registered events, but speciall character with Ctrl or Alt or Shift combinations are not supported at this time. This is what I'm asking, how to get Ctrl + Comma, Ctrl + Alt + Dot and like combinations.

Comment: For three key, you could also use the above solution add an intersection condition `shift.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)`.